# A proof of Work-Energy Theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

As an exercise, I was working on a proof for the Work-Energy Theorem and I came up with a quite different solution compared to the ones I can find online (wiki etc), so I wanna ask you if my effort is right (but just too overcomplicated) .  So, here's my attempt:

Let **F**=$(F_x,F_y,F_z)$ and **s**=(x,y,z)

$W=\int F•ds$, (with F and s vector) then:

**F**•d**s**=$(F_x,F_y,F_z)•(dx,dy,dz)=(F_x dx)+ (F_y dy)+ (F_z dz)$

Then I split the integral in a sum of three (I show just for the x component):

$\int F_x dx=\int F_x v_x dt=m \int a_x v_x dt = m \int (dv_x/dt) v_x dt = m \int v_x dv_x=(1/2)mv^2_{x,B}-(1/2)mv^2_{x,A} $

the several integrals being calculated in their proper intervals, with B=end , A=start (struggling to put them in this formulas)

For y and z I have:

$\int F_y dy=(1/2)mv^2_{y,B}-(1/2)mv^2_{y,A} $

$\int F_z dz=(1/2)mv^2_{z,B}-(1/2)mv^2_{z,A} $

so that:

$W=\int F•ds= (1/2)mv^2_{x,B}-(1/2)mv^2_{x,A} + (1/2)mv^2_{y,B}-(1/2)mv^2_{y,A} + (1/2)mv^2_{z,B}-(1/2)mv^2_{z,A}$

and, rearranging these terms:

$W=\int F•ds= [(1/2)mv^2_{x,B}+ (1/2)mv^2_{y,B}+ (1/2)mv^2_{z,B}]-[(1/2)mv^2_{x,A} + (1/2)mv^2_{y,A}+ (1/2)mv^2_{z,A}]$

Here I'm not fully at ease with this last passage of my demonstration:

$W=\int F•ds= [(1/2)mv^2_B]-[(1/2)mv^2_A]$

Hope someone can tell me if what I've written is right and, if not, where the error(s) is(are)

Comment: The work energy theorem is a fairly straight forward principle. I think you are way overcomplicating it.

Comment: "a quite different solution compared to the ones I can find online..." It seems like you are presenting a pretty straightforward demonstration for the case of a single particle.

Comment: "I'm not fully at ease with this last passage..." I'm not sure how we can help with that. It is not clear what you are not at ease with.

Comment: Are you asking if $|\vec v|^2 = v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2$ for a 3d vector? It does.

Comment: See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/482449/work-kinetic-energy-theorem-derivation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hope someone can tell me if what I've written is right and, if not, where > the error(s) is(are)

Looks correct to me, for a single particle of mass $m$.

> here's my attempt:
>
> Let **F**=$(F_x,F_y,F_z)$ and **s**=(x,y,z)
>
> $W=\int F•ds$, (with F and s vector) then...

(Note: You can use the Latex/MathJAX notation "\vec{}" to write a vector. Also vector dot products usually look a little neater with the "\cdot" notations. I will use these notations.)

We have the starting point:
$$
W = \int \vec F\cdot d\vec{s}\;.
$$

If $\vec F$ is the *net force* (which it must be for the work kinetic energy theory to hold), we can write:
$$
W=\int m\frac{d\vec v}{dt} \cdot d\vec s 
$$
$$
= m\int d\vec v \cdot \vec v = \frac{m}{2}\int d(\vec v\cdot\vec v)\;,
$$
since $d(\vec v\cdot \vec v) = 2\vec v\cdot d\vec v$ by the product rule.

Also note that for vectors we usually use the notation $\vec v\cdot \vec v \equiv |\vec v|^2$. So we have
$$
W=\frac{m}{2}|\vec v_B|^2-\frac{m}{2}|\vec v_A|^2
$$