Trying to explain why $W = ΔKE$ and not $ΔE$
I read this and started to think; Confusion about the total work done on an object applied by an upward force
I understand the work-kinetic energy theorem, but this specific problem is causing me mental chaos.
Consider a crate that is lifted from $y=0 \ \text{m}$ to $y=h$ with $\Delta v=0 \ \text{m/s}$ here on the surface of the earth. It is clear that I (the lifter) added $mgh \ \text{Joules}$ worth of energy to the crate, but for some reason, gravity did not remove any energy from the crate. Both myself and gravity did work on the object, but my work was the only work that "counted" when it comes to $\Delta \text{E}$. Similarly, when I put the crate down, gravity is doing positive work, and I am doing negative work, and the crate indeed loses energy. Why is it all about me?
What is it exactly that is making my thinking wrong? It must be something to do with not considering the earth as part of the system, maybe?
I am thinking: if gravity was not present, and I did the same action, then all of my work would be converted into $\Delta \text{KE}$. However, since gravity is present, its function must serve to "undo" the work I did providing the crate with $\text{KE}$ because it's $\Delta \text{KE}=0$. So, by saying that the crate has $\text{PE}$ and that gravity countered my work, does it mean I am double counting the energy in some way?

This question is similar to: Work-energy theorem confusion. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

And see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/778301/

And see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#Work%E2%80%93energy_principle

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/748400


but for some reason, gravity did not remove any energy from the crate.

That’s not true. Gravity did negative work of $-mgh$ on the crate. The work is negative because the force of gravity is in the opposite direction to the displacement of the crate. When something does negative work on an object it takes energy away from the object. In this case gravity took away the energy you gave the object by your positive work and stores it as gravitational potential energy in the Earth-object system.
Keep in mind that potential energy is a system property. The object alone doesn’t possess gravitational potential energy (though it is common to say that). It’s the Earth-object system that possesses gravitational potential energy.
Hope this helps.

Work is about energy changing from one form to another. For example, when you lift the crate, you convert chemical energy into gravitational potential energy.
If you drop the crate, you convert potential energy to kinetic energy.
If you slide the crate at constant speed down a ramp with friction, you convert potential energy to heat.
Work tells you things about how much energy was converted.
And yes, one force can "undo" the work done by the other.
Imagine the crate sliding down a frictionless ramp and onto a floor with friction. Gravity converts potential energy into kinetic energy, and friction converts that to heat. Both do work. The net change in kinetic energy is $0$.
If friction and gravity act at the same time, you can imagine friction sucking up the kinetic energy as fast as gravity makes it. Again, you have two forces doing work so the total change in KE is $0$.

Both, myself and gravity did work on the object, but my work was the only work that "counted" when it comes to ΔE.
Here you have defined the object alone as the system which has two external forces acting on it, the upward pushing force and the equal magnitude downward gravitational force.
The upwards force does $+mgh$ amount of work and the gravitational force does $-mgh$ amount of work so the total work done by the external forces acting on the system (object alone) is $(+mgh)+(-mgh) = 0$.
This results in there being no change in the kinetic energy of the object.
$\dots$ by saying that the crate has PE and that gravity countered my work means I am double counting the energy in some way?
Not so you are looking at the contribution due to the work done by the internal gravitational force in two ways.
Here the system is the object and the Earth and as there is more than one mass involved the concept of gravitational potential energy can be used.
The external upward force does $+mgh$ amount of work and the internal gravitational force does $-mgh$ amount of work which represents an inflow of energy into the system and is stored in the system as an increase in gravitational potential energy.
Since the work done by the external force is equal to the gain in the gravitational potential energy there is no energy "left over" and so the kinetic energy of the object does not change.


I am thinking...if gravity was not present, and I did the same action,
then all of my work would be converted into $\Delta \text{KE}$.

This is basically correct. If we accelerate a $2 \ \text{kg}$ object at $9.8 \ \text{m/s}^2$ over a distance of $10 \ \text{m}$, then the work done is $2\times 9.8\times 10 = 196 \ \text{Joules}$. If, instead, we raise the object $10 \ \text{m}$ relative to the Earth's surface, then the work done in raising the object is the same, but instead of becoming $\text{KE}$, the $\text{PE}$ of the system is increased by $196 \ \text{Joules}$. This represents the work done by gravity in opposing your lifting of the object.
